# Button on top of a Link Component

Tags: reactjs

Hey I have a div which is wrapped by a Link component, and inside that div I have more buttons, but the problem is, when I click on the inner smaller buttons, I actually click on the Link component as well, so I get redirected which is not what I want... How do I fix this? I tried using zIndex but that did nothing.. Here's the component

```
<div className="post-container">
            <Link to="/test" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <div className="link-post-container">
                    <div className="post-content">{post.title}</div>
                    <div className="post-bottom-bar">
                        <div className="bottom-bar-container-padded">
                            <div className="bottom-bar-container" onClick={test.bind(this)}>
                                <div>Comments</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi @randomboiguyhere, I assume that your problem is between the `div` with class `.bottom-bar-container` and the `Link` component, right? Can you add the code for the `test` method that is being called when clicking in the `div`?

Comment: @mgarcia Yes, exactly, and the `test` method is just `console.log("clicked")`, so when I click on the .bottom-bar-container, it prints "clicked", but it also redirects me to /test, and I only want it to print the "clicked", without redirecting me

Comment: If you don't want the click on the `div` to trigger a redirect, why place it inside the `Link` element?

Comment: that is an invalid HTML Link is a wrapper of an anchor tag. Wrapping anything clickable inside a anchor tag is bad practice

Comment: @mgarcia because I want the whole div to be clickable, and then I want to make small buttons inside that div which does some other things

Comment: What I mean is, the `Link` is used to navigate to some URL when you click on it. Putting elements inside that do other things when clicked and avoid navigation seems weird. What do you want the whole div to be clickable for if you are avoiding the effect the click event has?

Comment: @mgarcia I am trying to make a replica of reddit, where they have a big div which holds the post text and things, but they also have a small bar at the bottom where you can click on links like Comment, Share and etc..

Comment: If you inspect the HTML of reddit, you will see that the post title is, indeed, inside an anchor tag. But the bottom bar with the links to comments, share, etc are contained within another div, that it is not a descendant of the anchor tag for the post title. In this way, the problem you are facing is not present :)

Comment: @mgarcia yes, but if you put your mouse under the "Comments" button for example, you can still click on the post. This is exactly what I am talking about.